# Tab System overflows into drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been asked to create a tab based interface to switch content without refresh. Which is fine and dandy, but the tab list items can be dynamically added creating a longer set of tabs. When they reach a certain point based on window width the overflowing tabs should 'fall' into a drop down menu giving users the option of opening a tab content div from there.

Personally I would have gone with tabs forming two lines but the requirement is for a drop down to the right very similar to Firefox's functionality when there are too many tabs open for the available width.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated as this is driving me mental!

Comment: This sounds more like a discussion, not really a question...

Comment: Can you show us the code for how the tabs are dynamically added?

Comment: Best to post up what code you have so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Responsive layouts might be what you are looking for:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/a-flexible-approach-to-responsive-navigation/

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/a-flexible-approach-to-responsive-navigation/ seems a viable solution, will work on it and post results here.